# Splitting numpy arrays & rearranging them

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I have 10 seconds of data from 7 devices each with 2 channels in a 1D array, sampled at 51.2KHz.

I split the array into to 10

`time_split = np.array_split(data, 10)`

I then split each element of `time_split` into the samples for each device

`device_split = [([np.array_split(d, 7) for d in time_split]`

`device_split.shape` gives `(10, 7, 51200)`

So thats 51200 samples for each of the 7 channels every second

OK so the bit that I'm struggling getting my head around. I want to reconstruct a time series for each device, for exmaple,

For device 0 I'm expecting an array of length 10 x 51200, that's 10 seconds of samples at 51.2KHz from that device.

I have tried,

`devices = device_split[:][0]`

`devices.shape` gives `(7, 51200)` so that `devices[0]` is just 1 seconds worth of data from device 0, not the full 10 seconds worth.

`device_split[:][:]` just returns the orginal array

What does work...

```
dev_0 = []
dev_1 = []
dev_2 = []
dev_3 = []
dev_4 = [] 
dev_5 = []
dev_6 = []

for sec in device_split:
    
    dev_0.append(sec[0])
    dev_1.append(sec[1])
    dev_2.append(sec[2])
    dev_3.append(sec[3])
    dev_4.append(sec[4])
    dev_5.append(sec[5])
    dev_6.append(sec[6])
    
dev_0 = np.array(dev_0).flatten()
dev_1 = np.array(dev_1).flatten()
dev_2 = np.array(dev_2).flatten()
dev_3 = np.array(dev_3).flatten()
dev_4 = np.array(dev_4).flatten()
dev_5 = np.array(dev_5).flatten()
dev_6 = np.array(dev_6).flatten()
```

It strikes me that there must ne a much more `numpy` way of doing this!

Is there?

Comment: Is the shape of data `(10, 7, 51200)`?

Comment: Instead of the splits can you just do `arr=data.rsshape(10,7,-1)`?  Would `arr..transpose(1,0,2)` be useful?  That would make a (7,10,51200)` shape.

Answer (score 0):

If the device_split shape is (10, 7, 51200) and the second axis corresponds to devices. You can get the i-th device data array with

```py
device_split[:, i]
```

In fact

```py
device_split[:]
```

returns the original array. Using ":" means taking all index from the axis. You should also read [numpy indexing doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html).

In addition, you can reshape the array instead of using array split if your data is a "flatten stack" as such

```
data.reshape(10, 7, -1)
```

where "-1" fits the remaining dimension ([see reshape doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)).